# listSelector update on item delete from ListView

Tags: android

I create a list shown in a "singleChoice" ListView, having a defined android:listSelector. The selection works fine as long as the list is not changed. Then I'd like to delete the selected item from the list, and switch the selection to the next item, or to the last one, in case before I deleted the last one. The following code delete the items as expected, but I don't know how to switch the selector to the next item after delete.

This is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="#ffcccccc"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_delete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/listview_1"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="onClick_delete"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView1;
    android.widget.ArrayAdapter<String> ArrayAdapter1;
    int iRow;
    Button buttonDelete;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_delete);

        ArrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        ArrayAdapter1.add(new String("row 1"));
        ArrayAdapter1.add(new String("row 2"));
        ArrayAdapter1.add(new String("row 3"));
        ArrayAdapter1.add(new String("row 4"));

        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_1);
        listView1.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter1);

        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                iRow = position;
                buttonDelete.setEnabled(true);
            }
        };

        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
    }

    public void onClick_delete(View v) {
        int count = ArrayAdapter1.getCount();

        if (count - 1 < iRow)
            iRow = count - 1;

        String row = ArrayAdapter1.getItem(iRow);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Deleting: " + iRow + " - \"" + row + "\"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        ArrayAdapter1.remove(row);
        ArrayAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

        if( 0 == ArrayAdapter1.getCount())
            buttonDelete.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

I developed on Android Studio 3.6.1, with Nexus 4 API 23 emulator.

I tried to force the switch of the selector using listView1.performItemClick or listView1.setItemChecked, but it didn't work. I appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use custom view and custom data  for `listview` to achieve that instead of simple string of array , that way you can store each state of row in it.

BTW when you call `ArrayAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();` the whole list will reloads again maybe you could use `listView1.setItemChecked` after `ArrayAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();` i cant assure you that will work.

Comment: I already tried ```listView1.setItemChecked``` after ```ArrayAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged()``` without success, but I'll try custom view and custom data as you recommended.